# Replace a specific range of values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have big data set and there are tons of values which are way over average.
For example,

```
    A         B
1  'H'       10
2  'E'    10000
3  'L'       12
4  'L'        8
5  'O'       11
```

and I want to set `B2` cell as 0 and I tried this,

```
df['B'] = df['B'].replace([df['B'] > 15], 0)
```

But didn't get any luck.
How can make my data frame like this,

```
    A         B
1  'H'       10
2  'E'        0
3  'L'       12
4  'L'        8
5  'O'       11
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are really close - instead of `replace`, use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask(df['B'] > 15, 0)
print (df)
     A   B
1  'H'  10
2  'E'   0
3  'L'  12
4  'L'   8
5  'O'  11
```

Alternative:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'] > 15, 0, df['B'])
print (df)
     A   B
1  'H'  10
2  'E'   0
3  'L'  12
4  'L'   8
5  'O'  11
```

If you want replace some range:

```
df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].between(8,11), 0, df['B'])
print (df)
     A      B
1  'H'      0
2  'E'  10000
3  'L'     12
4  'L'      0
5  'O'      0
```

Comment: Watch out with 'np.where'. For some reason it removes the data type of the whole column.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative:

```
df.loc[df['B'] > 15, 'B'] = 0
#   df
#    B
#0  10
#1   0
#2  12
#3   8
#4  11
```

Comment: Chokes on `DataFrame`s that have a `MultiIndex`.