# How to replace a range of values of a Dataframe column with NaN using Numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with the column `RH_1`:

```
    RH_1
   --------
    36.999
    34.555
    36.777
    33.688
    38.999
    37.667
    ...
```

I want to replace a set of numbers falling within a certain range with `NaN`. For ex. I want all the values in that column within the range 36-37 to show `NaN`.

So my preferred output will be like:

```
    RH_1
   --------   
    NaN
    34.555
    NaN
    33.688
    38.999
    37.667
```

So I was using this code:

```
train['RH_1']=train['RH_1'].apply(lambda x: np.NaN if(x in range(36,37)) else x)
```

But when I do `train.isnull().sum()` it still shows there are no null values in that column and also I don't get any error for executing that code.

P.S. I prefer it to be done using `np.where()` under `lambda` function, since I'm practising that. Alternative solutions are also requested, if any, using a simpler method.

P.P.S. I checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168450/replace-specific-range-of-values-in-data-frame-pandas), however it is replacing by certain values and also not selecting a `in range(..)`.

Comment: That question, takes in the whole dataframe into account and not a particular column. I've tried  to implement for the particular column, but didn't workout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) for boolean mask with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
train['RH_1'] = train['RH_1'].mask(train['RH_1'].between(36,37))
```

Or:

```
train['RH_1'] = np.where(train['RH_1'].between(36,37), np.nan, train['RH_1'])
print (train)
     RH_1
0     NaN
1  34.555
2     NaN
3  33.688
4  38.999
5  37.667
```

Comment: `<built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at 0x0000024F42A6D710> returned a result with an error set`. I'm getting an error. Also like how is your method filling in `NaN` instead?

Comment: @DebadriDutta - Check edited answer.